# Spring data neo4j Cypher, search between two longs

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher

Actually I try to get list of objects via user id, startDate and endDate,
dates are stored as long.

```
@Query(
            "START  email=node:__types__(className='com.backend.core.neo.entities.Email') "            
            + "WHERE  email.senderId={0} AND email.searchDate > {1} AND email.searchDate < (2)"
            + "RETURN email")
    List<Email> findBySenderIdAndSearchDateBetween(Long userId, long startDate, long endDate);


Query List<Email> findBySenderIdAndSearchDateBetween(Long userId, long startDate, long endDate);
```

is not working, always `return 0`,

and I don't know how can I do it with Cypher query.

Comment: or where is a mistake 
  @Query("START email=node:com.backend.core.neo.entities.Email WHERE email.senderId={0}"
            + " AND email.searchDate > {1} AND email.searchDate < {2}"
            + " RETURN email")
    List<Email> findBySenderIdAndSearchDateBetween(Long userId, long startDate, long endDate);